# Need to iterate over a Python list in reverse as fast as possible

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iteration

I'm using Python 3.2.3. What's the fastest way to iterate over a list in reverse? [::-1], reversed, list.reverse() or maybe some other way? I'm dealing with a list of about 5e6 elements or so, so I really need to avoid copying the list.

Comment: You should test it out yourself. I recommend you check out the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> t = Timer('[x for x in l[::-1]]', 'l = list(range(100000))')
>>> t.timeit(number=1000)
5.549649953842163
>>> t = Timer('l.reverse(); [x for x in l]', 'l = list(range(100000))')
>>> t.timeit(number=1000)
4.548457145690918
>>> t = Timer('[x for x in reversed(l)]', 'l = list(range(100000))')
>>> t.timeit(number=1000)
4.428632974624634
```

Conclusion: reversed() is marginally faster than l.reverse() on a list with 100000 items.
This of course is even more true if you don't actually loop over the whole list, and it stops being true if you use the list more than once.

`l[::-1]` is outdated since 2.4 that introduced `reversed()`.

Comment: I find `l.reversed()` almost on par with iterating through the original list ordering: (`t = Timer('[x for x in l]', 'l = list(range(100000))')`) with Python 3.8.  A lot can happen in 9 years, I suppose.

Answer (score 15):

`reversed` should be best as it returns an iterator, so it doesn't copy the list, just yields one element at a time.  (`list.reverse()` also will not copy the list, but it will mutate it, so the list will be backwards after you're done, whereas `reversed` doesn't modify the original list.)

Comment: Note that iterators don't *necessarily* prevent copying, it just happens to work in this case.

Comment: That's true, but in general the built-in python functions that provide iterators don't construct the whole list at once; that's the whole point of them.